# Returning to HTTP after Devise SSL controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to redirect requests to HTTP after `Devise` actions. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is the right/best way so I'm open to suggestion. Here's what I have and it's failing with a "redirect loop", which is understandable. Now I just need to figure out how to terminate the request after the redirect.

Is this worth pursuing, or is there a better way?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :https_only_for_devise

  @@ssl_controllers = ['devise/registrations',
                        'devise/sessions']

  def https_only_for_devise
    if (@@ssl_controllers.index(params[:controller]) == nil)
      redirect_to :protocol => 'http://'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think I have solved this... just testing it on EngineYard right now... will post the result...

Comment: If you use https only for devise, and not across the entire site, you leave your users open to being [firesheeped](http://codebutler.com/firesheep). You should instead require https across the entire site. With rails-3.1, you can set `config.force_ssl = true` in your `production.rb`.

Comment: That's interesting... I didn't think of that. I guess the performance hit is small compared to security risks?

Comment: The performance hit for SSL is minute when compared to the performance hit for the privilege of running a Rails application. The benefits of course are, respectively, increased security and increased programmer happiness.

Comment: Going once... going twice... SOLD!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it worked! Changed the content of the method to:

```
  def https_only_for_devise
    if (@@ssl_controllers.index(params[:controller]) == nil && request.ssl?)
      redirect_to :protocol => 'http://'
    end
  end
```

Incredibly obvious now that I've thought about it...